# Relation between $\limsup\;$ and Bounded Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, sobolev-spaces, limsup-and-liminf

> Let $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow [0,+\infty)\;$ be a smooth function that
>   vanishes on a finite set $A$ where $\vert A \vert \ge 2\;$. If
>   $a_1\;,a_2\;\in A\;$  consider:
>
> $\mathcal M= \{\;v\in W^{1,2}_{loc} (l^{-},l^{+});\;-\infty \le
>  l^{-} \lt l^{+} \le +\infty\;,\;\lim_{x \to l^{-}}
>  v(x)=a_1\;,\;\lim_{x \to l^{+}} v(x)=a_2 \neq
>  a_1\;\;,\;v((l^{-},l^{+}))\subseteq \mathbb R \setminus A \}$
>
> It also holds $\int_{l^{-}}^{l^{+}} f(v(x))\;dx\lt \infty\;$

***Question:*** Assume a sequence $\{v_n\}\;\subset \mathcal M$ for which $\;\limsup_{\vert v_n \vert \to \infty} f(v_n) \gt 0\;$. Is this sufficient in order to conclude $\;\{v_n\}\;$ is a bounded sequence? It holds $\int_{l^{-}}^{l^{+}} f(v_n(x))\;dx\lt \infty\;$ but somehow this is not enough for the sequence to be bounded.

If it's true, I would appreciate if somebody could explain why...and if it's not I would like to know by which assumption(s) on $f$, $\;\{v_n\}\;$ is bounded.

Unfortunately, I can't come up with any good idea. Any help would be valuable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is $\mathcal M$ a subset of $\mathbb R$ or $W^{1,2}_{loc}$? In the latter case, what is $|v_n|$ and what do you mean by "bounded"? What is $v$ in the assumption?

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz I believe $\mathcal M\;$ is a subset of $W_{loc}^{1,2}\;$. $v\;$ is a map $v:(l^{-},l^{+})\rightarrow \mathbb R\;$ defined by $\mathcal M\;$.